# How to wait for response from mutation and pass it to another one?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I have form which is responsible for POST Cooking Recipes to my API written in ASP.NET CORE WEB API.

My onSubmit function have 2 steps. First step is sending raw data to API. Second step is sending images as FileData to my server.

Now here appears my problem. After first step my server is returning me added Recipe Data as response. Now i need to get RecipeId from response and pass it to my second step, but recipeId is always null.

After second submitting this form everything works fine and images are sent to server.
How to correctly wait for my recipeId and pass it to uploadImageMt()?
Some code for broader view.

My fetch functions for Adding Recipes and Uploading Images

**CreateRecipe**

```
export async function addRecipe(recipe: IAddRecipeRequest) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL_RECIPES}/addRecipe`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(recipe),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200)
      throw new Error(data[0].errors[0].errorMessage);

    return data.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error with adding product: ${err}`);
  }
}
```

**UploadImage**

```
export async function uploadImage(images: FileList, recipeId: number) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_UPLOAD_URL}?recipeId=${recipeId}`;

    if (images.length === 0) return;

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      console.log(images[i]);
      formData.append('images', images[i]);
    }

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200)
      throw new Error(data[0].errors[0].errorMessage);

    return data.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error with uploading image: ${err}`);
  }
}
```

And now I have created appropriately hooks

**CreateRecipe**

```
export function useCreateRecipe() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [recipeId, setRecipeId] = useState<number | null>(null);

  const { isLoading: isCreating, mutate: createRecipeMt } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (recipe: IAddRecipeRequest) => addRecipe(recipe),
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      toast.success('Recipe added');
      setRecipeId(data.recipeId);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['recipes'],
      });
    },
    onError: (err: Error) => {
      console.log(`err`, err.message);
      toast.error(`Something went wrong`);
    },
  });

  const getRecipeId = () => {
    return recipeId;
  };

  return { isCreating, createRecipeMt, getRecipeId };
}
```

**UploadImage**

```
export function useUploadImage() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { isLoading: isUploading, mutate: uploadImageMt } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: ({ images, recipeId }: UploadImageParams) =>
      uploadImage(images, recipeId),
    onSuccess: () => {
      toast.success(`Images added`);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({
        queryKey: ['images'],
      });
    },
    onError: (err: Error) => {
      console.log(`err`, err.message);
      toast.error(
        `Something went wrong`
      );
    },
  });

  return { isUploading, uploadImageMt };
}
```

**onSubmit:**

```
const { isCreating, createRecipeMt, getRecipeId } = useCreateRecipe();
const { uploadImageMt } = useUploadImage();
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = (data) => {
    const recipe: IAddRecipeRequest = {
     //BORING DATA MAPPING
    };

    createRecipeMt(recipe);
    const addedRecipeId = getRecipeId();
    if (selectedImages && addedRecipeId) {

      uploadImageMt({ images: selectedImages, recipeId: addedRecipeId }); 
    }
  };
```

Returning getRecipeId() in hook is an example of one of the attempts to achieve my goal but it's not working also.

If there is any other approach to situations like this please describe how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to asynchronous nature of JavaScript. When you call createRecipeMt(recipe), it starts the asynchronous request to add a recipe, but the getRecipeId() immediately after it doesn't guarantee that the recipe has been added and recipeId has been set yet.
You need to use await and the async keyword to ensure that createRecipeMt completes before attempting to upload images. Try something like this,

```js
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = async (data) => { // add async keyword here
  const recipe: IAddRecipeRequest = {
    // BORING DATA MAPPING
  };

  try {
    const addedRecipe = await createRecipeMt(recipe); // Wait for recipe creation

    if (selectedImages) {
      await uploadImageMt({ images: selectedImages, recipeId: addedRecipe.recipeId });
      toast.success('Images added');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`err`, err.message);
    toast.error('Something went wrong');
  }
};
```

Another alternative approach would be to have a uploadedRecipeId state in your component, which will be set when a recipe is uploaded. Use that as a useEffect dependency to trigger image upload. 
Before triggering image upload have a condition to check uploadedRecipeId is not null. Once image is uploaded, set uploadedRecipeId to null again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers! Works perfectly as I wanted :)